# Memory leak when using .NET ThreadPool

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, c#-3.0, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I am using **System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()** to run my tasks.

When running my application, I noticed it is taking a lot of memory and I took a dump file using the task manager. Investigting it, I found that many threads were stuck in the following stack:

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+a 
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+79 
mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+174 
mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+63 
mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+7b 
mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+11a 
mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+78 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

or

```
ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+a 
ntdll!TppWorkerThread+2c9 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

Why are these threads stuck? Am I using the wrong API? Maybe I am not managing the threads correctly?

Comment: show us the code that you run using  QueueUserWorkItem

Comment: They are threadpool threads waiting for work to do, you probably took the minidump when the program stopped being busy.  Several ways to tell if worker threads are doing what you expect them do, like do work and drive up CPU utilization, another way you can tell is that your program uses a lot more memory :)  Two threads can (almost) allocate twice as much memory as one.  The standard reason for having too many TP threads is not using them effectively or not throttling QUWI calls.  A Q&D band-aid is calling ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads().

Comment: Hello @jgauffin I'm using this code: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters)); and I'm also getting same memory errors due some threads seems to keep open somehow. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue seems to be high CPU. According to:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/27/net-debugging-demos-lab-4-high-cpu-hang-review.aspx

When CPU is over 80%, new threads will pend.